# assign product to a user mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, product

I have a list of products and users. I'm trying to assign products to a specific user. How should I set it up in database. I don't need php code for now as I have no idea how to connect the data in MySQL? I'm planning to use check-box pass the post info for the db.

Thanks,

Comment: table with 2 fields: user_ip | product_id

Comment: If you need data consistency, use foreign keys, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a many-to-many relationship between your product and user table as @Dragon suggested. Let's say you have table call `user_products` with two fields `userId` and `productId`.

Now you can assign as many product to a person by inserting an entry in this new table, e.g. userId is 100 and productId is 10,11,12

```
 INSERT INTO user_products (userId,productId) VALUES (100, 10);
 INSERT INTO user_products (userId,productId) VALUES (100, 11);
```

Hope you got an idea!

Comment: Oh, I understand now. The userId repeats itself for different productId. Cool, thanks guys. That makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

In your products tables add a user_id field which will contain the 'id' field of the users table.

For example

id | user_id | product_name | product_desc

If you wanna select the products based on specific user

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Comment: yeah, but I need to assign more products to one user.Not just one product to one user. And also I need to add boolean value for if it's checked. I'm going to do this for OpenCart. There is one function that does this but in that case "products can have only one download". And I understand that but I don't know how you can have multiple values in one column for one row? It's all confusing unless there is in db input type that allows multiple values...